# SSMS Alter Table Row not being accessed anywhere else

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a temp table to store data from a csv and then altering the table after to create a new column to identify each row by a unique number in ascending order.

This gets created fine, however I can't query the table using these row numbers. Seems as if it doesn't get set. On SSMS when I use the newly created column it red lines it with the error *Invalid Column Name 'columnName'* but I can still query the database.

```
declare @loopNum INT
set @loopNum = 0

    CREATE TABLE #A
    (
        column1 BIGINT NOT NULL,
        column2 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    )

    DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(150)
    SET @command = just reads from file into temp table A. this works fine
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @command

    ALTER TABLE #A
    ADD RowNumbers INT IDENTITY(1,1)
 --if i run a select * from #a, all 4 columns show perfectly
while @loopNum <= 5
begin
select * from #a where loopNum = RowNumbers -- doesn't return anything yet loop is going up one as 6 blank results are returned
set @loopNum = @loopNum + 1   
end
```

The select statement doesn't recognise "RowNumbers" so I'm not sure if there's a problem with how I've done the alter command.

This is what I get so far.

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | RowNumbers
A        | B        | 1
C        | D        | 2
```

It just doesn't loop through it.

Comment: why do you do ALTER TABLE to get the column RowNumbers in ? why not put it into the create ?

Comment: I'm not sure how many rows of data would come in. I assume there is a way around this though?

Comment: Without knowing what your trying to do its hard to answer. You could create a cursor to loop through table #A then you dont need a counter, Mind you, cursors are not good for performance, but a loop also is not

Comment: What are you trying to do here though? Like, why do you need to a) create a column after you created the table instead of during the create b) loop through the row numbers at all? You could use a window function and avoid the whole loop routine.

Comment: Plan is to read in a csv file into two columns in a tempTable. From there I need to go through each row on the temp table and do some queries, hence the reason for why I need to add in a unique column and a loop. Thought about adding a new column which increments one number at a time ... which it does. Just can't query on this new column as it doesn't seem to exist

Comment: The column exists but 0 will never be equal to 1. And loopnum <> @loopnum

Comment: @JacobH A. Not entirely sure on how to create this during the bulk insert. and B. Will be doing queries on each row on this temptable

Comment: Why are you using a loop at all? There is no need to use a loop to select data from a table like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues here.

One, you're going to get an empty row first always because you declared @loopNum = 0 and your `WHILE` loop starts at 1.

Two, you are using "loopNum" instead of your variable @loopNum in your `SELECT`.

Rextester: http://rextester.com/XJNML62761